# Type does not conform to protocol 'URLRequestConvertible' with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Here's the code:

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    //Error: Type 'Five100px.Router' does not conform to protocol 'URLRequestConvertible'

    static let baseURLString = "https://api.500px.com/v1"
    static let consumerKey = "MY_KEY"

    case PopularPhotos(Int)
    case PhotoInfo(Int, ImageSize)
    case Comments(Int, Int)

    var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {

        let (path, parameters) : (String, [String: AnyObject]) = {

            switch self {

            case .PopularPhotos(let page):
                let params = ["consumer_key": Router.consumerKey, "page": "\(page)", "feature": "popular", "rpp": "50", "include_store": "store_download", "include_status": "votes"]
                return ("/phtos", params)

            case .PhotoInfo(let photoID, let ImageSize):
                var params = ["consumer_key": Router.consumerKey, "image_size": "\(ImageSize.rawValue)"]
                return ("/photos/\(photoID)", params)

            case .Comments(let photoID, let commentsPage):
                var params = ["consumer_key": Router.consumerKey, "comments": "1", "comments_page": "\(commentsPage)"]
                return ("/photos/\(photoID)/comments", params)
            }
        }()

        let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)
        let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL

        return encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    }
}
```

I imported Alamofire and added this code, then comes the error. I wrote this code according to raywenderlich tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial, which is written in Swift 1.2 while I use Swift 2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to return an `NSMutableURLRequest` in the `URLRequest` property instead of an `NSURLRequest`. That will fix up the error.

---

### Update

In Swift 3 and Alamofire 4, you need to return a `URLRequest` from the new `asURLRequest()` method. For more details, please refer to our much more detailed README [examples](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#api-parameter-abstraction).

Comment: This is not works for SWIFT3, i am return URLRequest  like this : `func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest`

Comment: That is correct @PiyushSanepara, this above only works in Alamofire 3. In Alamofire 4, you need to implement the `asURLRequest()` method to conform to `URLRequestConvertible`. More info can be found [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#api-parameter-abstraction).

Answer (score 1):

@cnoon's answer works for version 3, but if you're using Alamofire version 4+, you will have to implement:

`func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest`

Comment: where we need to implement this. 
My enum is defind in this types - 
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible { }

I'm getting same problem with swift 3.0

Comment: that's exactly where you need to implement it. Within your enum. This is where you customize the returned URLRequest object based on each case in your enum. By customize I mean set the http method and headers, set the timeout, encode the parameters, etc....

Comment: refer to the Routing Requests section of the Alamofire 4.0 documentation in here: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#routing-requests