# Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.1 Migration - Alamofire request error

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsurlrequest, urlrequest

I am converting an existing project that used **Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.1**.
So far, I am successful in implementing all changes as per Xcode suggestions, and also added latest PODs.

Everything seems to be fine except the following - (Since this is an already existing code, I partially understood what's being done).

I have a below request -

```
var request = ModifyProfileAddressAPIRequestData()
request.clientContext = ClientContext()
request.customer = AddressContext(address: CustomerAddress(countryName:countryName, countryCode: countryCode, locationName:locationName,houseNr: houseNr, streetName: streetName, postalCode:postalCode, box: box ))           
request.fields = "customer.address"
let parameters = request.toJSON()

DDLogVerbose("modifyProfileURL parameters JSON:\(parameters)")

alamofireConfigure().request(request).validate(statusCode: 200..<503).responseObject{ (responseData: DataResponse<UserProfile>) in

...
```

And the **ModifyProfileAddressAPIRequestData** is a Mappable Struct as below -

```
fileprivate struct ModifyProfileAddressAPIRequestData : Mappable{

    var customer: AddressContext?
    var clientContext: ClientContext?
    var fields:String?

    init() {}

    init?(map: Map) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {        
        customer <- map["customer"]
        clientContext <- map["clientContext"]
        fields <- map["fields"]
    }    
}
```

I get an error in the alamofireConfigure request as 
`Argument type 'ModifyProfileServiceAPIWithAlamofire.ModifyProfileAddressAPIRequestData' does not conform to expected type '`URLRequestConvertible`'`

My other requests, are successfully changed by following the solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32740096/type-does-not-conform-to-protocol-urlrequestconvertible-with-alamofire) and it works without any problem.

My only problem is with the request of type Mappable. It works well in Swift 2.3.

Could someone throw light on what is actually happening and what need to be done to resolve this issue occurring in Swift 3.1 please?

Comment: did you got any error ?

Comment: Yes, it is mentioned in the question - 'Argument type 'ModifyProfileServiceAPIWithAlamofire.ModifyProfileAddressAPIRequestData' does not conform to expected type 'URLRequestConvertible''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer my own question. I made changes to the request as below (Please see my question for the original code)

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: modifyProfileURL)!)

                var data = ModifyProfileAddressAPIRequestData()
                data.clientContext = ClientContext()
                data.customer = AddressContext(address: CustomerAddress(countryName:countryName, countryCode: countryCode, locationName:locationName,houseNr: houseNr, streetName: streetName, postalCode:postalCode, box: box ))
                data.fields = "customer.address"
                let parameters = data.toJSONString()

                request.httpBody = parameters?.data(using: .utf8)
                request.httpMethod = "POST"
                request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                request.setValue("Bearer \(accessTokenRequest.accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")


                alamofireConfigure()
                    .request(request)
                    .validate(statusCode: 200..<503)
                    .responseObject{ (responseData: DataResponse<UserProfile>) in
.
.
.
```

I basically distinguished between the URLRequest and my data. Hence the Mappable Struct remains same (as in my question).

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement this method to conform `URLRequestConvertible` as is defined in Alamofire.swift

```
/// Types adopting the `URLRequestConvertible` protocol can be used to construct URL requests.
public protocol URLRequestConvertible {
    /// Returns a URL request or throws if an `Error` was encountered.
    ///
    /// - throws: An `Error` if the underlying `URLRequest` is `nil`.
    ///
    /// - returns: A URL request.
    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest
}
```

I think you need

```
fileprivate struct ModifyProfileAddressAPIRequestData : Mappable,URLRequestConvertible{

    var customer: AddressContext?
    var clientContext: ClientContext?
    var fields:String?

    init() {}

    init?(map: Map) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {        
        customer <- map["customer"]
        clientContext <- map["clientContext"]
        fields <- map["fields"]
    } 

    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest{
        if let url = URL(string:"your http://......"){
            return URLRequest(url: url)
        }else{
            return URLRequest()
        }

    }    
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, and I have a question. How can I send an empty URLRequest? I mean, in the case of "if let" failure condition?

Comment: You can return an empty URLRequest, but you don´t will have any answer of course from your server, my answer was edited